# Is it possible to set a Lifestyle for an injected Java Resource

Tags: java, dependency-injection

My background is .NET and I am used to being able to set a lifestyle (Singleton, PerInstance...) for my dependencies using things like Castle Windsor.

I have recently moved to a Java project where the code uses @Resource to inject dependencies. I have looked around but cannot find a way to specify a lifestyle. Does the concept exist or am I just rubbish with my searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource annotation is used to obtain **container managed** resource (EJB, JMS Queue, etc.) from JNDI so I think you don't have control over life-cycle and what you call lifestyle.

For some fine-grained application component dependency injection using some CDI framework like Spring or Weld (reference impl. for Java EE 6) is way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't move the code to use Spring CDI at the moment so will keep it in mind for next time.

Answer (score 1):

This concept of lifestyle does not exist in native Java. The closest concept I can think of is probably Spring's prototypes / singleton scopes.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch04s04.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring dependency injection module. Detailed [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html)